Car battery replacement _DIY?
I have a 2018 honda hrv. I have started noticing that everytime I turn on the car, it cycles through power on/off multiple times. I am assuming that it is time to replace my car battery. Photos below of the car battery. I have not replaced car battery, so it has been more than 5 years of usage.
For now, I use a battery jump starter, and it works. Can you please let me know if I can replace car battery by myself, and what are things I need to consider before doing it.
I am not sure what the light bluish mineral is on the positive terminal of the battery.



We don't know your capabilities so we have no possible way to know if you can change a car battery correctly and safely. There is an element of danger. Please watch a few videos on YouTube and you decide if this is something you can do, then come back for any concise questions that you may have. (I can think of one: "Does this battery need to be replaced?" because it is not clear what you mean by "cycles through power on/off".) Also let us know if you have a digital voltmeter or not, or if you can borrow one.

As noted above, watch a few YouTube videos to get an idea of what's involved. Short answer is probably yes, it's very simple, but research first then decide. The bluish color is corrosion, which can be cleaned with a battery terminal cleaner.

Keep in mind that in many places auto shops will replace the battery for you for a very low cost, or even free.

Most auto stores selling car batteries provide free battery tests.  Decide, as mentioned previously, if you have tools and comfortable about removing and replacing. The wet powdery deposits is battery acid vapors, venting, depositing nearby. A warm water solution of baking soda and toothbrush will dissolve and neutralize this immediately.  Paper towels to wipe clean. Battery terminal cleaner contains the same ingredients plus a sticky grease (and solvent) to forestall future buildup of battery acid venting.

As suggested, I used baking soda and water to the terminal to remove the corrosion. It seems I don't need to replace the battery. The car is running smoothly for now.
In addition to backing soda and water, I sprayed the terminal with WD-40 contact cleaner. No issues with the car power.

Congratulations on solving the immediate battery problem! My advice is to start thinking about where you're going to get a replacement battery now, well before there is any sort of "oh crap my car won't start" moments. If that battery is original equipment, I suspect it's going to be due for a replacement soon.
